# Is that possible to use Eclipse Java SE version to package a resource folder into a .war?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications

I am using Eclipse Java SE Indigo. Is it possible to use this Eclipse  (rather than Java EE Eclipse) to wrap the source folder containing my applets to a .war?

In addition, in my source folder, there are some .txt files explaining the functionalities of these applets.

In particular, I feel reluctant to update my Java SE Eclipse to the Java EE one, because too many plug-ins were already installed under my older Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create zip-files easily in Java (specially if you use 1.7). A war-file is just a zip-file that follows [a few conventions](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-2.4-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/). Why not write a Java class that zips the content of your bin-folder (or wherever eclipse stores its classes) into a suitable war-format?

Run-time Java resources should be added into the `WEB-INF/classes` folder of your war-file, so you will be able to get to them using `aClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`; outside of `WEB-INF` and `META-INF`, files are generally web-accessible (unless your web.xml says otherwise).

If you do not feel like building it by hand, you can also use [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html), either from inside or outside Eclipse, to automate war-building. This is the route I would recommend; but then again, I like to be able to build and package my projects from both inside and outside the IDE...